# Find palindromic words in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, palindrome

I am trying to find all the palindromic words in a column in a data frame 'data' which looks like:

```
name year amount 
 James 2010  934706
 Aza   2010  21042
 Rory  2010   869691
 Suzanne 2010 651674
 Felicity 2010 386115
 Oliver   2010  382388
 Anna     2010   43211
```

I have tried:

```
palindrome <- function(word) {
rawWord <- charToRaw(tolower(word)) ## converts to lower case
 sprintf("%s is %sa palindrome", word,
    c("not ", "")[identical(rawWord, rev(rawWord)) + 1])
     }
palindrome(data)
```

But this returns a list of "mary is not a palindrome" "anna is not a palindrome" ... etc
I want to be able to subset only the words that *are* palindromic and then return them to the data frame in order to correlate them to the other columns to find when they occured and how many times.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763518/reverse-digits-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following steps.

```
rawdata <- sapply(tolower(data$name), charToRaw)

# Array of booleans. TRUE if palindromic. FALSE if not
ispalindrom <- unlist(lapply(rawdata, function(x) identical(x, rev(x))))

# Palindromic words
data[ispalindrom,]

# Non palindromic words
data[! ispalindrom,]
```

Comment: This returns all of the non palindromic words but for some reason it returns <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) when I use "data[ispalindrom,]" even though I know there are palindromic words.

Comment: Could do give an example of the data you are working on?

Comment: I have included the first few rows of what the data frame looks like-I'm not sure if that helps? It was imported from a .txt file

Comment: See my edited answer which should work with your data

Answer (score 2):

I wondered about efficiency, so I wrote the same algorithm but using characters:

```
palchar <-function(nfoo) {
spfoo<-list()
ispalindrom<-vector()
rawdata <- sapply( 1:length(nfoo), function(j) strsplit(tolower(nfoo[j]), '') )
    ispalindrom <-unlist(sapply(1:length(nfoo),function(j) identical(rawdata[[j]],rev(rawdata[[j]]))) )
    return(ispalindrom)
}
```

The relative performances are:

```
 nfoo<-rep(nfoo,10)
 microbench0mark(palbyte(nfoo),palchar(nfoo))
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
 palbyte(nfoo) 7.154999 7.435734 7.538363 7.648477 124.8712
 palchar(nfoo) 9.224697 9.531945 9.713685 9.850097 127.2356
 neval
   100
   100
```

(Yes, I get the same actual answer from both algorithms)