# R Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers

Tags: r, palindrome

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Write a program that ﬁnds the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question is unclear, please read and edit your question according to [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that other users can help you. Also, add expected output and code that you have tried.

Comment: Related in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7183977/680068

Comment: Related post in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763518/reverse-digits-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
ispalindromic <- function(x) {
  return(all(utf8ToInt(x) == rev(utf8ToInt(x))))
}

v <- 100:999
l <- sapply(as.character(outer(v,v)), ispalindromic)
r <- as.numeric(names(tail(which(l),1)))
```

Comment: A while loop that checks from the largest number down should be substantially faster. `l <- as.character(outer(v,v)); k <- TRUE; i <- length(l); while (k) { if (ispalindromic(l[i])) { print(l[i]); k <- FALSE; }  i <- i - 1 }`.

Comment: @Axeman yes, that's true, searching from the tail would be much faster